# Best way of programming kivy

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I use kivy and am a fan of the kv language. However, I cannot get my head around the best way to integrate it with python code. For example, here is a simple tabbed screen, defined totally in kv language. But how to I access the kv items in python? Say I want to switch tabs as indicated by the  button and its associated code. What should the references 'something' and 'some header' be in python?

```
#Tabbed Control

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):  
    def Switch(self):
      # something.switch_to(some header)
      pass

class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   BasicApp().run()
```

with kv code

```
#Tabbed Control

MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Alpha'
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                Label:
                    text: 'Alpha content area'
                Button:
                    text: 'Switch to Beta'
                    on_press: root.Switch()
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Beta'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Beta content area'
```

I'd really like to know what others do. I know that kivy objects can be generated in the python code. But then you loose the simplicity, compactness and separation provided by kv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is described [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code). You have to create properties referencing toyour panel and the target tab:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#Tabbed Control

<MainScreen>:
    tab_panel: tab_panel
    beta_tab: beta_tab
    TabbedPanel:
        id: tab_panel   
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Alpha'
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                Label:
                    text: 'Alpha content area'
                Button:
                    text: 'Switch to Beta'
                    on_press: root.Switch()
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Beta'
            id: beta_tab
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Beta content area'
''')

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):  
    tab_panel = ObjectProperty(None)
    beta_pad = ObjectProperty(None)
    def Switch(self):
        self.tab_panel.switch_to(self.beta_tab)


class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   BasicApp().run()
```